# How to send the contents of Jenkins workspace as email attachment following the run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

How can the contents of Jenkins build workspace be sent as an email attachment, following a test run?. Below is my declarative pipeline code snippet. I can see the folders and files in the workspace following pipeline run, but it doesn't attach except the build log:-

```
stage('Send Test Report') {
            steps {
                script {
                    
                    def testEmailGroup = "saba@abc.com"
                    // Test teams email
                    emailext(
                              subject: "STARTED: jOB '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]' RESULT: ${currentBuild.currentResult}",
                              attachLog: true, attachmentsPattern: "**/${WORKSPACE}/*.zip",compressLog: true,
                              body: "Check console output at   ${env.BUILD_URL}" ,
                                          
                            to: testEmailGroup)
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to drop workspace contents into a file, here is a snippet similar of what we have on our Jenkins:

```
stages {
        stage('CreateAndSendReport') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Contents" > contents.txt'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'contents.txt', onlyIfSuccessful: true
            
          
                
            emailext attachLog: true, attachmentsPattern: 'contents.txt',
                body: "${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME} build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\n Link: ${env.BUILD_URL}",
                recipientProviders: [developers(), requestor()],
                subject: "Jenkins Build Report  ${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME}"
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: It still wouldn't work. I added  these lines to the 'post' section:-   archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'target/*.jar', onlyIfSuccessful: true,fingerprint: true      
emailext attachLog: true, attachmentsPattern: 'target/*.jar',